# How to read a pixel off of the screen?

Tags: macos, opengl, screen-scraping, pixel

I am trying to make a simple bot for a web game, so I would like to be able to read the color of a pixel on the screen. I've done this on Windows with GetPixel(), but I can't seem to figure it out on OS X. I been looking online and came across glReadPixel. When I made a simple command line tool in XCode, I put in the following code. However, I cannot seem to make it work. I keep getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error from this:

```
GLfloat r;
glReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, GL_RED, GL_FLOAT, &r);
```

I thought the above code would store the red value of the pixel at (0,0) into r. Oh, I'd like to avoid take a screen shot approach because that is slow. Any help?

P.S. With the command line tool, my end goal is to make a bash script or an applescript, since I already have a command line tool that can click on the screen.

Comment: Do you have an active OpenGL context when you call `glReadPixels()`?

Comment: Nope. Could you please point me in the proper direction?

Comment: I'd like for the active OpenGL context to be the main screen.

Comment: In most OS you can't get OpenGL context for the whole screen. There are some workarounds, but I don't recommend their use. Most OS give you screen grabbing facilities though. You already know the Windows variant (GetPixel on the Screen DC). This is highly OS specific so you've to rewrite the code for each OS you want to support. OpenGL is mostly focused on getting things on the screen.

Comment: Oh I see. Is there a OSX equivalent to GetPixel on the Screen DC?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395420/get-the-color-a-pixel-on-the-screen-in-objective-c-cocoa-app This will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 4):

`glReadPixels` is only concerned about reading a pixel from the frame buffer (the area into which your graphics card draws).

Reading pixels from the "screen" is not related to OpenGL at all. You need system-specific functions for that.

Comment: Oh thanks. Would you happen to know how I would be able to get a screen pixel on a mac?