# Objective c Color coding?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, colors

I'm wondering if there is any way in xcode to look at an image and, based on a CGPoint (a coordinate on the screen) find a specific pixel and figure out its color.

For example, look at the bottom of this image. Look at the colored square that the  ^  is pointing at.

[image]
______________^

Let's say that each individual colored square is a CGPoint, the one being pointed at is at `ccp(30,30);` What color of blue is on that CGPoint?

Is there any way to scan this and do something like possibly a function that checks a CGPoint and returns a number that represents a certain color?

Comment: The answer here may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395420/get-the-color-a-pixel-on-the-screen-in-objective-c-cocoa-app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see [here](http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/) how to get pixel color in a CGPoint.
You'll get an UIColor.