# Fast get pixel in OS X + Python

Tags: python, macos, pixel, getpixel

I want to get the rgb value of an arbitrary pixel on the screen.  Preferably without having to load a full gui toolkit like qt or gtk.  Taking a screenshot works, but it's an expensive operation and I'd like to run this thing in real-time, so I would have to take multiple screenshots per second.  On Windows I can do `windll.gdi32.GetPixel(dc,x,y)`.  Any Mac equivalent?

Comment: This thread might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395420/get-the-color-a-pixel-on-the-screen-in-objective-c-cocoa-app