# Detect color under macOS mouse cursor

Tags: objective-c, macos, colors, detect

I want to know how to get the color of the pixel where the OS X / macOS mouse pointer currently is located.

I programmed a console application, so I have no window to overlay or something else.

When I build and run the program, it should give me a console log of the color where my mouse pointer currently is. Is that possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395420/get-the-color-a-pixel-on-the-screen-in-objective-c-cocoa-app) as a starting point, this is a fully functional command line program.

```
// To build and run, save this file as main.m, then:
//
//   clang -framework Foundation -framework Cocoa main.m
//   ./a.out

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  CGDirectDisplayID mainDisplayID = CGMainDisplayID();
  // NSLog(@"Main display id=%d", mainDisplayID);

  while (true) {
    @autoreleasepool {
      CGPoint cursor = CGEventGetLocation(CGEventCreate(NULL));
      // NSLog(@"Mouse pos: (%f, %f)", cursor.x, cursor.y);
      CGRect rect = CGRectMake(cursor.x, cursor.y, 1, 1);
      CGImageRef image = CGDisplayCreateImageForRect(mainDisplayID, rect);
      NSBitmapImageRep *bitmap = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:image];
      CGImageRelease(image);
      NSColor *color = [bitmap colorAtX:0 y:0];
      NSLog(@"%@", color);
      [bitmap release];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you very very much! this is exactly what I'm searching for! Again, thank you ;-) but one thing, releasing bitmap in release pool, is this really necessary?

Comment: It's necessary because the bitmap in this example is not autoreleased. It's alloc'd. The @autoreleasepool only drains autoreleased objects.

Comment: For what it's worth, the coordinate systems didn't match up for me. I had to do...
mouseLoc = {screenHeight} - mouseLoc.y + 20;

Comment: Getting the mouse position by passing CGEventCreate(null) into CGEventGetLocation will give you it in the right coordinate system FYI. NS and CG use different coordinate systems.