# DigitalColor Meter logic - how does it do it?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So, this basically what I'm curious about :

- How does this little tool get the area (and the specific pixel) below the mouse?
- How does it then analyze the RGB values of that selected point?

Any ideas? Pointing me to the right direction would also be welcome.

---

**Hint** : *I would be more interested in a native Objective-C/Cocoa approach.*

Comment: This answer might point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746471/detect-color-under-mouse-mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, DigitalColor Meter gets the mouse coordinates, takes a CGImageRef screenshot around that area and then accesses the raw pixel data to calculate the RGB value.

You can discover which APIs an application calls by using the `nm` command.  In this case:

`nm /Applications/Utilities/DigitalColor\ Meter.app/Contents/MacOS/DigitalColor\ Meter`

Which reveals some interesting calls:

```
U _CGDisplayBounds
U _CGGetDisplaysWithPoint
U _CGSCaptureWindowsContentsToRectWithOptions
U _CGSCurrentInputPointerPosition
U _CGSGetOnScreenWindowCount
U _CGSGetOnScreenWindowList
```

The CGS* routines are private SPI - on the bright side, there is a public API equivalent called `CGWindowListCreateImage()`

Once you have a CGImageRef, you can access the raw pixel data using:

```
CGImageGetDataProvider
CGDataProviderCopyData
```