# Search color and do something -Apple Script-

Tags: macos, colors, window, applescript, screen

I use to use a windows PC but now i have a Macbook so this is my problem:

I need some help in AppleScript to do this: search in a certain ponint or area of a window or screen then if detect a X color press one key and if the color is not detected then press another key.

I made it before in Autohotkey but there is no version of this for Mac, so that's why i am trying to do it in the AppleScript.

This is an example of how i got it in Autohotkey:

---

Coordmode, Pixel, Screen

Action1:
FoundX := 0
FoundY := 0
PixelSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 1821, 1025, 1868, 1033, 0x666666, 3, Fast
If (ErrorLevel = 1)
Goto, Action2

```
Send, {F2}
Sleep, 133      
Send, {F3}
Sleep, 333
Goto, Action1
```

Action2:
FoundX := 0
FoundY := 0
PixelSearch, FoundX, FoundY, 1760, 1025, 1800, 1040, 0x5498FF, 5, Fast
If (ErrorLevel = 1)
Goto, Action1

```
Send, {F1}
Sleep, 333
Goto, Action1
```

---

Comment: AppleScript itself doesn’t know anything about a point on the screen, you would need to use something else - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11746471 may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to keystroke <kbd>F2</kbd> and the <kbd>F3</kbd> key. AFAIK, the F keys can only be triggered using [`key code`](https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes) so here is a version that should work. Do note that I don't know anything about Autohotkey so you might have to tweak the code a bit:

```applescript
try
    set theClipboard to the clipboard -- this just stores your clipboard for later use.
    set n to true
on error
    set n to false
end try
tell application "Digital Color Meter"
    launch
    tell current application to activate
    delay 0.1
    tell application "System Events"
        click menu item "Copy Colour as Text" of front menu of menu bar item "Colour" of front menu bar of application process "Digital Colour Meter"
        if (the clipboard) is equal to "255 255 255" then key code 160 -- If it doesn't work, try key code 99
    end tell
    quit
end tell
if n then set the clipboard to theClipboard
```

The colors are stored in RGB and the current script presses <kbd>F3</kbd> if the color under the current mouse position is white.