# Pixel picking in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa

I am trying to create a functionality (for a macOS 11+ application) where I pick a pixel from the screen (e.g like the one from Digital color pickier/ any color picker). However, I am having a hard time finding a way to do that.

I tried to "reverse engineer" some applications from AppStore and when I want to pick the pixel, the apps ask me if I want to give permission to record the screen, so I guess that they are "recording the screen" and they exact the pixel from a movie/picture that they record on the spot. However, this solutions does seems a little bit overkill and I think there should be a better way (a good example is Digital Colour Meter that does not ask for permissions).

Do you think that this can be achievable in a somewhat easy and clear manner? Also, if not, is my guess right with "recording the screen" and capturing a pixel from within the clip (of course, in real time)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the color a pixel on the screen in objective-c cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395420/get-the-color-a-pixel-on-the-screen-in-objective-c-cocoa-app)

Comment: I recall hearing this mentioned in one of the more recent WWDC videos, that they added a standardized colour sampling control that doesn't require the screen-reading permission. However, I can't seem to find it now that I"m searching for it.

Comment: @pkamb It answer and it does not anwser. After I implemented the code from the question that you indicated, it seems that this is the solution for "record the screen" thing. (thank you for this, at least now I know eactly how is implemented). I am more looking for a method that does not require you to acces screen recording permisions.

Comment: I found it! It's [`NSColorSampler`](`https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolorsampler`), first available in 10.15 (Catalina). It doesn't require the screen recording permission. It's described in [WWDC 2019, Session 210, What’s New in AppKit for macOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/210) around the 5 minute mark

Comment: @Alexander, your effort put into this is incredible. I can't thank you enough. please submit this as an answer so I mark your answer as resolved. Thank you very much once again

Comment: I gotta thank [wwdc.io](https://wwdc.io/), and its ability to search within WWDC video transcripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NSColorSampler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolorsampler) was introduced in macOS 10.15 (Catalina). You can use it to sample a color from the screen using the system's built-in color picking interface. It does *not* require screen-recording permissions.

It's mentioned around the 5 minutes mark in [WWDC 2019, Session 210, What’s New in AppKit for macOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/210)

I would probably wrap it, and take a hybrid approach where I use old methods (with the screen permission prompt) on old versions, and NSColorSampler for new versions.